# I can't seem to get my website's mobile nav to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-material-design

I have been creating a website and I am using Bootstrap 3.2.0 with a material design theme. When I go on my website and resize the window to be smaller and click on the button to open the nav nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
<html lang="en">     
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="material/dist/css/ripples.min.css"></link>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="material/dist/css/material-wfont.min.css"></link>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fezvrasta.github.io/snackbarjs/dist/snackbar.min.css"></link>

<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"></meta>
<body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-warning">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-warning-collapse" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Python for Beginners</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-warning-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Learn</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

This is the material theme's site: http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#about

I haven't made a JSFiddle because I'm not sure how to add bootstrap to it.

The site is online at: pythonforbeginners.site90.com

Comment: To add Bootstrap to a fiddle, open the "External Resources" pane on the left and enter the URL of your favorite CDN in the input box. Example CDN: //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js (js), //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css (css).

Comment: Here's [your HTML with all the dependencies included](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/96ksp2cd/). In your example above, you don't link to any of the javascript libraries involved besides jQuery.

Comment: no script tags in code shown ... is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the bootstrap script--without it that stuff wont work. Add this to your doc, below your jQuery script tag:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```